# Is there a way to add a text (link) to the original data?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am crawling some sites.

The link is not correct.
The page does not open.

So I want to add a link to the original data

Or maybe there is a better way than I think.

Please let me know if there is a good way

-Ex-

[[A wrong address]]

/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=7&dirId=70111&docId=280474152

[[The text you want to add]]

I would like to add an address to the front of my code(# Bulletin url)

Http: // ~ naver.com

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)


# Bulletin URL
list.url = 'http://kin.naver.com/qna/list.nhn?m=expertAnswer&dirId=70111'

# Vector to store title and body
titles = c()
contents = c()

#  1 to 10 page bulletin crawling
for(i in 1:10){
  url = modify_url(list.url, query=list(page=i))  # Change the page in the bulletin URL
  h.list = read_html(url, encoding = 'utf-8')  # Get a list of posts, read and save html files from url

  # Post link extraction
  title.link1 = html_nodes(h.list, '.title') #class of title
  title.links = html_nodes(title.link1, 'a') #title.link1 to a로

  article.links = html_attr(title.links, 'href') 
  #Extract attrribute

  for(link in article.links){
    h = read_html(link)  # Get the post

    # title
    title = html_text(html_nodes(h, '.end_question._end_wrap_box h3'))

    title = str_trim(repair_encoding(title))

    titles = c(titles, title)

    # content
    content = html_nodes(h, '.end_question .end_content._endContents')

    ## Mobile question content
    no.content = html_text(html_nodes(content, '.end_ext2'))

    content = repair_encoding(html_text(content))

    ## Mobile question content
    ## ex) http://kin.naver.com/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=8&dirId=8&docId=235904020&qb=7Jes65Oc66aE&enc=utf8&section=kin&rank=19&search_sort=0&spq=1
    if (length(no.content) > 0)
    {
      content = str_replace(content, repair_encoding(no.content), '')
    }

    content <- str_trim(content)

    contents = c(contents, content)

    print(link)

  }
}

# save
result = data.frame(titles, contents)
```

Comment: convert the url to a string connect it with the string (Http: // ~ naver.com) you have. save the output and add it to the list you want. It would be even more intelligent to do that before you run the string. You could check if the url has "http..." if not add it. I would write the code and post an answer but I have no idea about R...

Comment: I know R but I didn't understand what you want to do. Could you provide an expected output or something else to help me understand?

Comment: @F.Privé Florian.prive.21@gmail.com Can I send mail here?
(Detailed explanation, executable file ...) If you give permission, I will send mail in two hours.

Comment: Yes, if you want, but it would be better to be accessed by anyone so that anyone could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `article.links <- paste0("http://kin.naver.com", article.links)` before the forloop, this seems to work (running).